# Memory usage of infinite lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell, memory, ghc, lazy-evaluation

This code is using only 1Mb of RAM:

```
main = putStrLn $ show $ length (take 2000000 [1..])
```

While this code is using [90Mb of RAM](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9358390/):

```
nums :: [Int]
nums = nextInts 0
  where
    nextInts x = x : nextInts (succ x)

main = putStrLn $ show $ length (take 2000000 nums)
```

If I change it like this, it will be using again 1Mb of RAM:

```
nums :: [Int]
nums = nextInts 0
  where
    nextInts x 
        |x == 90000000 = []    -- some large number
        |otherwise = x : nextInts (succ x) 

main = putStrLn $ show $ length (take 2000000 nums)
```

**Question:** Can someone explain why second code sample are storing whole list in RAM, while third isn't doing it. Also describe how I should change second sample to use O(1) RAM and to be still infinity list.

Comment: `putStrLn . show` is `print`

Comment: `nums` is exactly the same code as `iterate` (sources for library functions can be found by Hoogle)

Comment: This isn't what's going on in your case: but sometimes GHCi will keep the whole list in RAM just because it's in the root scope.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the second case your memory usage is not coming from storing the list but from building up unevaluated thunks from the use of `succ x`.

`succ` is lazy, so calling `succ x` just allocates a new thunk on the heap. This thunk never gets evaluated because you never need to know the value of any of the list elements.

In the third case you are forcing the evaluation of `x` by using the guard `x == 9000000` and therefore the thunks are not building up.

Comment: Yeah you are right, using `seq` in second sample works

Comment: How come the GC doesn't collect those thunks as they are made?

Comment: Because the thunks form a chain, i.e. the thunk for x=4 refers to the thunk for x=3 which refers to the thunk for x=2, etc. When `take` passes over the list element x=4 we can't garbage collect it because the new head of the list is x=5 which refers to the thunk x=4.